# Is it possible for a monk to practice/become proficient in more than one monastic tradition?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, archetype

Reading p. 79 of the PHB, under the heading “Monastic Traditions”, it is somewhat unclear to me as to if it is possible for a monk to choose more than one tradition.  Part of my confusion comes from the fact that “a few (monasteries) honor the three traditions and instruct each monk according to his or her aptitude and interest”. The paragraph goes on to mention a “diverging” but not necessarily excluding the possibility of pursuing training in multiple traditions.

Comment: @Rukara: I’m not certain if this is multiclassing the same class twice (if it is, then yes the answer to the above says “no” and I’m good with that, just want to make sure). Currently creating a Dragonborn Monk and working on a backstory (with a view to his future monastic life)

Comment: You're right that it's not "multiclassing" in a literal sense, but it is in a functional sense. If you look at the substance of the other question, you'll see that it is asking the same fundamental question you are. Put another way, you are inquiring about "multiclassing" into a clone of the same class but with a different archetype.

Comment: @Rykara: gotcha.  part of my problem here (it seems to me) is a whole new vocabulary. I’ll run with the answer as “no it’s not possible”.